# HighCharts : Multiple Charts resulting in multiple export button

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

This is my first time using **High Charts** library, great stuff.

Anyway, i am facing a strange problem that i don't understand the reason behind it or how to solve it.

When i display one chart in my page everything is good as soon as i add more charts in the same page the added charts have two export buttons.
[image]

here is my JS code :

```
$(function() {
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    colors : [ '#e74c3c', '#66b354', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5',
                            '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4' ]
                });

                /* Pie Chart */
                $('#pie-chart-1')
                        .highcharts(
                                {
                                    chart : {
                                        plotBackgroundColor : null,
                                        plotBorderWidth : null,
                                        plotShadow : false
                                    },
                                    title : {
                                        text : '#{msg['DB_graph_title1']}'
                                    },
                                    tooltip : {
                                        pointFormat : '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                                    },
                                    plotOptions : {
                                        pie : {
                                            allowPointSelect : true,
                                            cursor : 'pointer',
                                            dataLabels : {
                                                enabled : true,
                                                color : '#000000',
                                                connectorColor : '#000000',
                                                format : '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },                                      
                                    series : [ {
                                        type : 'pie',
                                        name : 'Etat',
                                        data : [
                                                //'#{msg['DB_graph_ND']}'
                                                [ '#{msg['DB_graph_ND']}',
                                                        #{homeSupBean.nonDemarre} ],
                                                [ '#{msg['DB_graph_CL']}',
                                                        #{homeSupBean.complete} ],
                                                [ '#{msg['DB_graph_EC']}',
                                                        #{homeSupBean.enCours} ], ]
                                    } ]
                                });
            });


            $(function() {
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    colors : [ '#95ceff', '#66b354', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5',
                            '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4' ]
                });
                $('#container-1')
                        .highcharts(
                                {
                                    chart : {
                                        type : 'column'
                                    },                                      
                                    title : {
                                        text : '#{msg['DB_graph_title2']}'
                                    },
                                    subtitle : {
                                        text : ''
                                    },
                                    xAxis : {
                                        type : 'category',
                                        labels : {
                                            rotation : -45,
                                            style : {
                                                fontSize : '13px',
                                                fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    yAxis : {
                                        min : 0,
                                        title : {
                                            text : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} (%)'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    legend : {
                                        enabled : false
                                    },

                                    tooltip : {
                                        pointFormat : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} : <b>{point.y:.1f} %</b>'

                                    },                                      
                                    series : [ {
                                        name : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']}',
                                        data : [
                                                <ui:repeat value="#{homeSupBean.profils}" var="prfl">[
                                                        '#{prfl.profileName}',
                                                        #{homeSupBean.profilProg[prfl.id.toString()]}],
                                                </ui:repeat> ],
                                        dataLabels : {
                                            enabled : true,
                                            rotation : -90,
                                            color : '#FFFFFF',
                                            align : 'right',
                                            format : '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                                            y : 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                                            style : {
                                                fontSize : '15px',
                                                fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } ]
                                });
            });
            $(function() {
                try {
                    Highcharts.setOptions({
                        colors : [ '#95ceff', '#66b354', '#DDDF00',
                                '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263',
                                '#6AF9C4' ]
                    });
                    $('#container-2')
                            .highcharts(
                                    {
                                        chart : {
                                            type : 'column'
                                        },
                                        title : {
                                            text : '#{msg['DB_graph_title3']}'
                                        },
                                        subtitle : {
                                            text : ''
                                        },
                                        xAxis : {
                                            type : 'category',
                                            labels : {
                                                rotation : -45,
                                                style : {
                                                    fontSize : '13px',
                                                    fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        yAxis : {
                                            min : 0,
                                            title : {
                                                text : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} (%)'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        legend : {
                                            enabled : false
                                        },
                                        tooltip : {
                                            pointFormat : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} : <b>{point.y:.1f} %</b>'
                                        },
                                        series : [ {
                                            name : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']}',
                                            data : [
                                                    <ui:repeat value="#{homeSupBean.campagnes}" var="camp">[
                                                            '#{camp.name}',
                                                            #{homeSupBean.campagneProg[camp.id.toString()]}],
                                                    </ui:repeat> ],
                                            dataLabels : {
                                                enabled : true,
                                                rotation : -90,
                                                color : '#FFFFFF',
                                                align : 'right',
                                                format : '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                                                y : 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                                                style : {
                                                    fontSize : '15px',
                                                    fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } ]
                                    });

                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                }

            });
            $(function() {
                try {
                    Highcharts.setOptions({
                        colors : [ '#95ceff', '#66b354', '#DDDF00',
                                '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263',
                                '#6AF9C4' ]
                    });
                    $('#container-3')
                            .highcharts(
                                    {
                                        chart : {
                                            type : 'column'
                                        },
                                        title : {
                                            text : '#{msg['DB_graph_title4']}'
                                        },
                                        subtitle : {
                                            text : ''
                                        },
                                        xAxis : {
                                            type : 'category',
                                            labels : {
                                                rotation : -45,
                                                style : {
                                                    fontSize : '13px',
                                                    fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        yAxis : {
                                            min : 0,
                                            title : {
                                                text : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} (%)'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        legend : {
                                            enabled : false
                                        },
                                        tooltip : {
                                            pointFormat : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} : <b>{point.y:.1f} %</b>'
                                        },
                                        series : [ {
                                            name : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']}',
                                            data : [
                                                    <ui:repeat value="#{homeSupBean.sectionsHC}" var="sect">[
                                                            '#{sect.name}',
                                                            #{homeSupBean.sectionProg[sect.id.toString()]}],
                                                    </ui:repeat> ],
                                            dataLabels : {
                                                enabled : true,
                                                rotation : -90,
                                                color : '#FFFFFF',
                                                align : 'right',
                                                format : '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                                                y : 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                                                style : {
                                                    fontSize : '15px',
                                                    fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } ]
                                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                }
            });
```

I tried this :

```
exporting : {
            buttons : {
               contextButtons : {
                        enabled : false,
                        menuItems : null
                        }
                },
                enabled : true
            },
```

but without success :(, if anybody can help please don't hesitate, thanks.

Comment: A little weird that for some charts you define exporting and for some you don't. If you want it enabled just don't add it in the config object since it's enabled by default.

Comment: Your code (now) looks fine. I guess the problem is somewhere else. Maybe you include `exporting.js` multiple times? Two things to mention though: 1) `$(function() { ... })` - use it just once, and create all charts inside. 2) `Highcharts.setOptions({ ... })` - you can use this only once also, you don't have to set options for every chart. Instead I suggest to set `colors` inside chart's options.

Comment: yes you are right i found multiple exporting.js in template page can you add an answer so i can check it as solved